# How to force button to stay at tableView cell's bottom?

Tags: ios, tableview

I add a button as a subview to my tableviewcells. Works fine. But I can't seem to figure out, how to force it to always be at the bottom of the cell. (On top of the separator line if you will). The cell height varies, so a fixed position is not smart. But I have no clue how to add it with a dynamic position. Here's the code for adding the button:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
    action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"+1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 70.0f, 160.0f, 15.0f);
    [cell addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the autoresizing mask when adding the button. I think the setting you want is:

```
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Do this after adding the button to the cell.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Even though it sticks to top of the cell and not the bottom (When changing it to bottomMargin, the buttons stick in middle).

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the height of the cell and put the button's frame like this.

```
button.frame=CGRectMake(0,cellHeight-15,160,15);
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can I get or define cellHeight?

Comment: i'm not in my mac, but i remember this

cell.frame.size.height

Comment: Well it did work, but the position is still fixed and not always at bottom of cell (cell height is dynamical :( )

Comment: if you check the height of the row as in the method height for row, perhaps this solve the problem